# JavaScript Unkown Line of Code

Tags: javascript

W3Schools's game making tutorial contains the line

```
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
```

Without this line the game area will not appear, but I don't know why or what it means. What does this line do for the overall code and why does the game area disappear without it?

Comment: Best guess -- `this.canvas` is probably your canvas, and inserting it in the body makes it appear on your screen ???

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that it is your canvas being rendered to the DOM. So it is being inserted as the first child of the body element.

Next time post the whole block of code and not just one line. The keyword "this" is specific to it's context and if you leave the whole relevant block out all we can do is guess because we have no idea what the canvas property of that "this" is.

Answer (score -2):

Because that line says the browser that i want to insert canvas element here and if you dont write that line thats didnt give you